# Forking a website and work in it as my own

Tags: github

Sorry for this novice question.

What a want to do: I forked a website (superman.github.io) to write upon it and making it my website (batman.github.io).

Someone can help me with, How can I do this?

As a novice I have only changed the name, what's the next step?

Comment: https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/

Comment: I do not want to make changes in the main repository, I only want to have my website as theirs, and then work in it on my own.

Comment: When you fork a repo, the resulting repo is *yours*. You're free to work on it as you please.

Comment: Have you looked at the pages documentation https://pages.github.com

Answer (score 0):

Make changes..test.. then commit and push it(only when you are sure that you have done one significant change or corrected something or  added feature). If accepted your changes will be accepted.

This is the general cycle. You can try to learn why we use github?
The sole purpose is to version control. So after you forked it you work on your local copy (by cloning of course) and commit multiple times but when you think you have added a feature or corrected something on the code then you will push it to the original repository. Then make a pull request to remote original repository. If accepted then you be happy.. you have contributed something significant.